# Creating files on a time (hourly) basis

Tags: php, datetime, twitter

I experimenting with twitter streaming API,
I use Phirehose to connect to twitter and fetch the data but having problems storing it in files for further processing.
Basically what I want to do is to create a file named

```
date("YmdH")."."txt"
```

for every hour of connection.

Here is how my code looks like right now (not handling the hourly change of files)

```
public function enqueueStatus($status)
$data = json_decode($status,true);
if(isset($data['text'])/*more conditions here*/) {
  $fp = fopen("/tmp/$time.txt");
  fwirte ($status,$fp);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Help is as always much appreciated :)

Comment: What problems are you running into, exactly?

Also `fwirte ($status,$fp);` should be `fwrite($status,$fp);`

Comment: right about the fwrite :)
I want the file names to change every hour so I'll have 1 file for each hour of connection - thinking of it again, I t might as well work with this code..

Comment: still need a way to close the file and release the $fp resource...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the 'append' mode in [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) - this will either append to a file or create it.

```
if(isset($data['text'])/*more conditions here*/) {
    $fp = fopen("/tmp/" . date("YmdH") . ".txt", "a");
    fwrite ($status,$fp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Phirehose googlecode wiki:

> As of Phirehose version 0.2.2 there is
>   an example of a simple "ghetto queue"
>   included in the tarball (see file:
>   ghetto-queue-collect.php and
>   ghetto-queue-consume.php) that shows
>   how statuses could be easily collected
>   on to the filesystem for processing
>   and then picked up by a separate
>   process (consume).

This is a complete working sample of doing what you want to do. The rotation time interval is configurable too. Additionally there's another script to consume and process the written files too.
Now if only I could find a way to stop the whole sript, my log keeps filling up (the script continues execution) even if I close the browser tab :P